# Angular2 + CKEditor - observing changes

Tags: ckeditor, angular

There is no problem with observing changes but with connecting it with [(ngModel)].

Code:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  template: `

  <textarea [(ngModel)]="comment" name="editor1" id="editor1"></textarea>
  <div *ngIf="comment">
    {{comment}}
  </div>
  `
})

export class MainComponent {

  ngOnInit(){
     //this.editor = window['CKEDITOR']['replace']( 'editor1' );
     window['CKEDITOR']['replace']( 'editor1' )['on']('change', function( evt ) {
       this.comment = evt.editor.getData();
       console.log( 'comment = ' + this.comment );
     })
  }

  comment: any = "default";
}
```

So, default when the page load

```
  <div *ngIf="comment">
    {{comment}}
  </div>
```

Angular2 prints "default" text - correct.
The problem is when I edit the text in ckeditor. Then there is still "default" text, but in console thanks to:

```
console.log( 'comment = ' + this.comment );
```

the text is viewing properly. So what's the problem? Why {{comment}} see only the start version of "comment" variable? How to fix it? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

try to run it inside a zone:

```
export class MainComponent {
  constructor(private zone:NgZone){}
  ngOnInit(){
     //this.editor = window['CKEDITOR']['replace']( 'editor1' );
     window['CKEDITOR']['replace']( 'editor1' )['on']('change', function( evt ) {
       this.zone.run(function(){
         this.comment = evt.editor.getData();
         console.log( 'comment = ' + this.comment );
       });

     })
  }

  comment: any = "default";
}
```

Comment: `
{
  "name": "Story",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.9",
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "ejs": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.2",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.24"
  }
}
`

Comment: you missing a dependency to zone.js:  `"zone.js": "0.5.15"`